# Create plain white background in Cinema 4D

Tags: cinema-4d

I'm looking to create a plain white background in Cinema 4D, currently when I render its onto a black background, I essentially want the same but with white. I would like there to be NO shadows, reflects etc... just a plain white background.

Comment: Unfortunately this question isn't programming related so would not suit the stackoverflow site, buit it would suit just fine on [superuser](http://superuser.com/) or [Audio-Video Production](http://avp.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a "background" object to your scene and assign a material. You can get it trough the menu (Objects->Scene->Background).